# web.xml illegal value after recent change

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Eclipse is giving the following error whenever I try to expand the contents of a project in Project Explorer:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for AppName.".
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.IllegalValueException: Value 'Container' 
is not legal. (platform:/resource/AppName/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml, 81, 16)
```

The project is a spring mvc app, and the problem seems to be the syntax of the part of web.xml at which a JavaMail section was recently added.

The line of code throwing the error is marked in the following code segment:

```xml
<resource-ref>
  <description>
    Resource reference to a factory for javax.mail.Session
    instances that may be used for sending electronic mail
    messages, preconfigured to connect to the appropriate
    SMTP server.
  </description>
  <res-ref-name>
    mail/Session
  </res-ref-name>
  <res-type>
    javax.mail.Session
  </res-type>
  <res-auth>
    Container
  </res-auth> <!-- this line throws the error -->
</resource-ref>
```

Here is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>AppName</display-name>
  <description>Description of app.</description>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml, classpath:spring/tools-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AppName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-core-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AppName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.servlet.DatatablesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/datatablesController/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>AppName</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>datatablesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>datatablesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <!-- added the following for JavaMail -->
  <resource-ref>
    <description>
      Resource reference to a factory for javax.mail.Session
      instances that may be used for sending electronic mail
      messages, preconfigured to connect to the appropriate
      SMTP server.
    </description>
    <res-ref-name>
      mail/Session
    </res-ref-name>
    <res-type>
      javax.mail.Session
    </res-type>
    <res-auth>
      Container
    </res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**How can I resolve this error?**

Answer (score 3):

Remove the spaces like this:

```
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

Comment: Worked for me, the tag wasn't on one line. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

In res-auth tag you have mentioned it has container. Have you defined mail/Session in your server container ? in weblogic server or in tomcat server.xml.

The issue could be the reference for the mail/Session is missing in the Container.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html

Comment: Thank you.  But can you please show how to actually do what you are suggesting?  As in what syntax to place in which file?  I am using tomcat 8 behind apache in a CentOS 7 server box.  You mentioned `server.xml`.  What do I place in `server.xml`, and where in the file does it go? Is there anything else that I need to change?  I have just examined my `server.xml`, and it does not contain any reference to mail.

Comment: If you are not planing to have anything in the server.xml of the container,change the res-auth to APPLICATION instead of container.